# Regex for 10,000 through 100,000 to 150,000,000 and beyond

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I'm trying to dollar amounts between 10,000 to 150,000,000.

I got this from a stack user previously but only catches from 1,000,000 through 150,000,000

```
(?<!\d)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}){2,})(?!\d)
```

I tried reworking it for the last hour but can't and regex is a notorious head wreck :D anyone can update it to start catching from 10,000? Thanks!

Comment: Replace `{2,}` with `+`: `(?<!\d)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?!\d)`. But it will also match `150,000,000,000`, etc.

Comment: Why would you even need a regex for that? where does the input come from? how does it look like? why not use `int` and numeric comparisons?

Comment: Just cast it and check it programmatically.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That regex pattern would also admit 160,000,000, [see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/uwcV8E/1).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, you provided the last ones I asked for too. I'll sit down for some regex tutorials after this. Sick of wasting my time and others with regex questions!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thats fines its monetary values that can exceed 150,000,00 sorry my question title was not clear enough

Comment: [Posted the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532366/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\d)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLfzLM/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)` - Group 1: one to three digits followed with **one or more** (due to `+` quantifier) occurrences of a comma and thee digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks, @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 3):

One approach might be to use the generic regex for thousands, and then add a lookahead to restrict the lengths to the range you want:

```
^(?=.{6,11}$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it and compare it programmatically:

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {"numbers": ["10", "100", "200", "5,000", "10,000", "15000", "some weird stuff", "160,000,000"]}


def tester(number):
    try:
        number = float(number.replace(",", ""))
        if 10 * 10 ** 3 <= number <= 150 * 10 ** 6:
            return True
    except:
        pass
    return False

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df["in_range"] = df["numbers"].apply(tester)
print(df)
```

This yields

```
            numbers  in_range
0                10     False
1               100     False
2               200     False
3             5,000     False
4            10,000      True
5             15000      True
6  some weird stuff     False
7       160,000,000     False
```

Answer (score 0):

You current pattern could also possibly match `999,999,999,999` due to the repeating of 2 or more times for this part `(?:,\d{3}){2,}`

The pattern also uses only the `\d` which can match 0-9 and is not limited to 5 anywhere in the pattern.

---

Matching 3 digits after the comma, you could use use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` to match the separate range parts:

```
(?<!\S)(?:[1-9]\d\d?,\d{3}|(?:[1-9]\d?|1[0-4]\d),\d{3},\d{3}|150,000,000)(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[1-9]\d\d?,\d{3}` Match range 10,000 - 999,999
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[1-9]\d?` Match range 1 - 99
    - `|` Or
    - `1[0-4]\d` Match digits 100 - 149
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `,\d{3},\d{3}` Match range ,000,000 - ,999,999
  - `|` Or
  - `150,000,000` Match the max value
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?!\S)` Assert whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l2djYW/1)